# Selenium Webdriver and OpenLayers

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

I would like to check that the locations asset on map (openLayer) are the same with some asset in a row. What is the best way to do this? I'm using the TestNG framework.

Comment: TestNG is a generic unit-testing framework.  It is useful for organizing tests but does not provide any technology for specific testing domains.  In other words, TestNG neither helps nor hinders testing maps (or anything else).

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see an answer on this.

TestNG is just a unit test framework and not automation specific so you will need to do this in your test itself via code of comparing two variables.

1. Have your UIMap expected.
2. Look at the HTML and compare the other location with the UIMap you are expecting.
3. If they match you can re-use the map for the other place if it's a different page
4. If they match on the same page you will likely need to include a [#] after it to identify which element you want with that specific map.

I would assume the row you are after there should be an expected result you want from that, if so it might be good to check the rows as a whole for the result and be sure it's there unless you need it in a specific order.

If this isn't the answer you were hoping for to this question then please update your question to something more specific .